# array value at an index for which value hasn't been defined

Tags: c, initialization

in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[2][3] = {{1,2},{4,5,6}};

    printf("%d\n",a[0][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `0` - since the array wasn't initialized, is this output a result of some undefined behaviour?

Comment: This is well-defined. If you supply an incomplete initialization list, the rest is initialized with `0`.

Comment: @Barmar null terminator is for similar case of character array?

Comment: " since the array wasn't initialized" --> Not quite.  One array element was not _explicitly_ initialized, yet it was initialized - with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
> initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
> previously listed initializer for the same subobject;151) **all
> subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
> implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

and

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, its value is indeterminate. **If an object that has static
> or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:**
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;

So in fact this declaration

```
int a[2][3] = {{1,2},{4,5,6}};
```

is equivalent to

```
int a[2][3] = {{1,2, 0},{4,5,6}};
```

Answer (score 2):

The array was initialised. You’re defining a two-dimensional array that consists of two arrays of three integers each. For the first of these two you only give two values, and by default the missing one is initialised as zero, so your full array is {{1, 2, 0}, {4, 5, 6}. a[0][2] will give you that zero.

Comment: I suggest you note that if an aggregate (an array or structure) is initialized at all, it is initialized completely, with default initialization for missing initializers. If it has automatic storage duration (was defined inside a function without `static` or other storage class specifier) and there is no explicit initialization, its elements or members have unspecified values. (Objects with static storage duration are default initialized.)